# Faking an AJAX-y login box

Tags: javascript, jquery, mocking

I've been asked to prototype a login box for a project, with the goal of emulating how an AJAX-y login box would.

Idea is:

1. User types in username/password (any; again, this isn't hooked up to any DBs or anything yet) and hits enter
2. Throbber shows up for 3 seconds.
3. User info appears.

I've tried doing this with jQuery as per the below; anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="c/main.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--[if lte ie7]>
        #header #logo {margin-right: 100px;}
        <!-[endif]--> 
                <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery('#login-form').submit(function(){
                    jQuery('#login-form > *').hide();
                    jQuery('#throbber').show().delay(300).hide();
                    jQuery('#logged-in').show();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="utilities"><a href="">Volunteer</a><a href="">About Us</a><input type="text" /></div>
            <div id="header">
                <img src="i/logo.png" id="logo" />
                <div id="pnav-wrapper">
                    <ul id="pnav">
                        <li><a href="#">Upgrade Your<br /><span>Skills</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Browse<br /><span>Events</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Browse<br /><span>Jobs</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="login">
                        <form action="#" method="get" id="login-form">
                        Username: <input id="username" type="text" /><br />
                        Password:&nbsp; <input id="password" type="password" />
                        <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;">
                        </form>
                        <img src="i/throbber.gif" style="display: none;" id="throbber">
                        <p id="logged-in" style="display: none;"><strong>The Admin</strong><br />
                        Administrator
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, you all totally rock, but you're all wrong -- the issue was the jQuery declaration on line 4; the http/s-less protocol doesn't apparently work when dealing with local files (such as I was; probably should have mentioned that...). Regardless, accepted jensgram answer because he was closest to what I was wanting and was second after Kieran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delay()` only affects the queue for `#throbber` (and `300` is 0.3 second).

Instead, use the callback of `.hide()` to show `#logged-in` *after* `#throbber` has been hidden:

```
jQuery('#login-form').submit(function() {
    jQuery('#login-form > *').hide();
    jQuery('#throbber').show().delay(3000).hide(function() {
        jQuery('#logged-in').show();
    });

    return false;
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/8NtJJ/1/))

Comment: Accepting because it's accurate and very complete, plus you were second. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change delay to 3000, make the whole login-form hide rather than just the child elements, and this part is key... put the logged in showing code inside a callback function to be executed after the throbber is hidden... like this:

```
jQuery('#login-form').submit(function(){
    jQuery('#login-form').hide();
    jQuery('#throbber').show().delay(3000).hide(function(){
        jQuery('#logged-in').show();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/dbhCe/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#login-form').submit(function(){
                jQuery('#login-form').hide();

                jQuery('#throbber').show();

                window.setTimeout( function() {
                    jQuery("#throbber").hide();
                    jQuery('#logged-in').show();
                }, 3000);
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo

http://jsfiddle.net/6UwDn/2/

Comment: Your answer's great, but I went with jensgram's answer because your code was rendering the throbber outside the div I was wanting. Also, while literally pressing the "enter" key was how I phrased the question, I felt using the actual submit(); function was closer to what I was ultimately trying to accomplish. Thanks for answering regardless!

Comment: no problems it was put up as an alternate.. i found it a little easier to read mine but the answer you picked is closer to your code. Cheers.